# Trying to launch a file after being found Linux BASH

Tags: linux, bash

i am trying to launch a GCC file in Linux after i find it.I also need to give myself rights over this file because i do not own it,after that,i need to move the file to the directory in which i just started the sh script.

I am using the following command to find the file,chown it and rename it in my current directory.

```
find . -name ".*" -exec bash -c 'sudo chown root:root {}' \; -exec 'mv {} /root/customfile' \;
```

My question is,how can i run this GCC Compiled File and return its output to STDOUT ?

Comment: What is "a gcc file"?  gcc is a compiler.  You could use it to compile a program.  Are you asking about how to run the compiler on a file and then execute the resulting executable?

Comment: Yep,exactly,this is what i am asking,how i can run it afterwards.To be more precise,the file i am searching for has already been compiled by GCC and all i need to do is run it.

Comment: That `find` command is extremely un-selective. It will find *many* *many* files if they exist.

Comment: In the folder that i am searching there is exactly one hidden file.

Comment: In the folder that you are searching there are at least two entries that match ".*", namely the folder itself and its parent. When gcc compiles to an executable, the default name is a.out but it is almost always given a name related to the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are renaming it to `/root/customfile`, the command to run it is now `/root/customfile`.  Or if `/root/customfile` is a directory, the command is now `/root/customfile/.whateverthefilenameis`.

Because you are already spawning a shell, you might as well run all the commands in a single shell.

```
find . -name ".*" -exec bash -c '
    sudo chown root:root {}
    mv {} /root/customfile
    /root/customfile/$(basename {})' \;
```

If `/root/customfile` is the file name, then obviously change the last line.